# php mysql search by first initial

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a member directory in a mysql database. I want users to be able to search by first initial of first or last name. I currently have code that allows searching by initial but brings up any name that has the letter in it, regardless of whether it is the first letter or not. How do I set this to only return if the first letter of wither name matches that selected?

```
$sql="SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM stafftest WHERE FirstName LIKE '%" . $letter . "%' OR LastName LIKE '%" . $letter ."%'";
```

Comment: `FirstName LIKE '" . $letter . "%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$letter = mysql_real_escape_string($letter);
$sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM stafftest WHERE FirstName LIKE '" . $letter . "%' 
OR LastName LIKE '" . $letter ."%'";
```

All I've done is remove the first % signs. The percent sign tells the mysql like statement to match any character. So in effect, you are telling it to: 'match any character(s) (including start and end characters) and then find the letter L, then match any character(s).'. Changing this to use just one % at the end will sort your problem out.

Additionally, it's a good idea to use prepared statements if you can. PDO is handy for that.

Comment: No probs ;) If you get a chance, consider abstracting away from whatever database class / functions you're using now and building a wrapper class. Then of course you can try out things like PDO and mysqli, or even roll your own prepared statement helpers.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this just by wildcarding the *end* of the string, as others have mentioned. To avoid potential SQL injection, use it within a bound variable.

```
/* $db_connection is assumed to be a mysqli connection resource */

$query = $db_connection->prepare('SELECT ID, 
                                         FirstName, 
                                         LastName 
                                  FROM   stafftest 
                                  WHERE  FirstName LIKE ? 
                                  OR     LastName LIKE ?');
$search = $letter . '%';
$query->bind_param('s', $search);
$query->execute();
```

Note: you need to construct a PHP variable with the wildcarded string in, and bind *that* rather than putting the wildcards around the placeholder in the query.

Comment: I get an error re: unexpected ; on the line OR LastName. I also noticed an opening bracket before Select ID but nothing closing it. Your answer is a bit over my head, so I am trying to break it down a little but the syntax is being rejected by the browser when trying to upload the file with this code. What am I missing?

Comment: Ah, missed a closing bracket. Fixed that. Did you try omitting the `OR` part entirely? (Just to simplify it a little)

Comment: OK, now the page loads properly, but trying to search by any letter returns this error:  Search Contacts:

You may search either by first or last name

A | B | C |D |E |F |G |H |I |J |K |L |M |N |O |P |Q |R |S |T |U |V |W |X |Y |Z

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/troop97/public_html/oabtest.php on line 120

Comment: Line 120: $query = $db_connection->prepare('SELECT ID, 
                                         FirstName, 
                                         LastName 
                                  FROM   stafftest 
                                  WHERE  FirstName LIKE ? 
                                  OR     LastName LIKE ?');

Comment: Are you using the [`mysql` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) or the [`mysqli` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)? You need to be using the latter to be able to prepare statements (i.e. you need to create your database connection by using `$db_connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);`)

Answer (score 0):

this will search whose **first name** or **last name** start with `$letter`

```
"SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM stafftest 
 WHERE FirstName REGEXP '^".$letter."' OR 
       LastName REGEXP '^".$letter."'";
```

**[REGEX IN MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)**
**[PATTERN MATCHING IN MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)**

Happy 2 Help :)

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent the use of an index, if one were available? My thinking is that you'd have to run some function (in this case regex parsing) on every value, thus rendering an index useless.